# No distortions with Strokes in a Fisheye render (Cycles)?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fisheye

I would like to draw my the scene with strokes and render it for a dome view (fisheye 210º) but when i finished to draw and start the render, I have no fisheye distortion, everything is flat like a classic 3D camera.

I use Cycles for rendering.

Anyone get an idea how I can achieve that?

Thanks for your help,

Julien

Comment: did you set the camera lens to panoramic Fisheye Equidistant? It is hard to help you if you don't share information on how you set your scene.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Susu for answering, I found the answer here :
https://developer.blender.org/T70235

> "This task can be closed explaining that it's not a supported feature currently.
> T68991: Fisheye / panorama in EEVEE is the task to add this in the future."

Comment: If you are dealing with eevee then don't use the tag for cycles... It is hard to help if you don't share information or the information is not correct...

Comment: Yes I used Cycles, but both render engine can't render grease pencil tool with fisheye camera. It seems that it get is own rendering? I don't really understand but every informations I found says that this is not possible yet.

Comment: You can use a lens distortion node in the compositor

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea but it works only for 180° and less. I need 210° actually 